# Bash script to run with conditinal startswith

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I am writing a bash script, where i am doing ssh based on the condition..

1. I have a file from where i used to get the volume name ie `ldap_volList` it contains 500 odd volume names
2. From the main `ldap_volList` i further creating a variable based on defined volume names like `array_fxn1` and `array_fxn2`.
3. Another i am checking if the Variable not empty like `if [ ! -z "$ldap_volList" ]; then` which is provided as an `input` for the script and then further getting it into the if condition.
4. Further i am making certain if the volume that startswith with `fxn1` IE  `if [[ $ldap_volList == fxn1* ]]` then run the ssh command into a predifined host with the `array_fxn1` volumes and similar to other .
5. but it does work only for first if condition and just exits out without moving to second `if`  condition.

---

```
fxn1:    fsx1002_Ploverdose_scratch fsx1002_Ploverdose

fxn2:     fsx2002_Ploverdose_workareas fsx2002_Ploverdose_cache
```

Code below [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Plese enter LDAP Project Name"
read -p "Enter LDAP Project Name:" ldap_proj
ldap_volList=$(cat archive_dashboard/ldap-project-nismap.csv | grep "$ldap_proj" | tr "," "\t"| awk '{print $NF}'| tr -d '"')

array_fxn1=$(echo "$ldap_volList" | grep ^fxn1)    
array_fxn2=$(echo "$ldap_volList" | grep ^fxn2)

if [ ! -z "$ldap_volList" ]; then
   if [[ $ldap_volList == fxn1* ]] ; then
     for i in $array_fxn1;do ssh dbcl101 "row 0; vol show $i";done

   elif  [[ $ldap_volList == fxn2* ]] ; then
       for i in $array_fxn2;do ssh dbcl201 "row 0; vol show $i";done
   fi
fi
```

**Output:**

```
$ bash hotvscold-test.sh
Plese enter LDAP Project Name
Enter LDAP Project Name:Ploverdose



Last login time: 7/15/2022 06:02:12
  (rows)

Vserver   Volume       Aggregate    State      Type       Size  Available Used%
--------- ------------ ------------ ---------- ---- ---------- ---------- -----
fsx1002   fsx1002_Ploverdose_scratch dbc014_ssd02 online RW 7.32TB 2.81TB  23%


Last login time: 7/15/2022 06:02:39
  (rows)

Vserver   Volume       Aggregate    State      Type       Size  Available Used%
--------- ------------ ------------ ---------- ---- ---------- ---------- -----
fsx1002   fsx1002_Ploverdose dbc012_ssd02 online RW      15GB     7.47GB    0%
```

Please suggest any help.

Comment: did you try with bash -x to view variable value during execution?

Comment: @Lety, Variable is getting expanded and i see the value it returns.

Comment: That is almost the same question as your other one.  Do not ask help on the same code twice.  Reword your question, as you can see, no one really understand your requirement.  See [ask] and [mcve].  For your `if`, look into `=~` instead of `==`.